# Drag & Drop of text in visual studio causes exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms

in any project, dragging and dropping any text cause the following exception:
"An exception has been encountered, This may be caused by an extension
You can get more information etc.
"

the activity log contains this:

```
<entry>
    <record>631</record>
    <time>2017/05/03 01:47:18.828</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>(see below)</description>
  </entry>
```

The description is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
>      at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DoDragDrop(IDataObject dataObject, IOleDropSource dropSource, Int32 allowedEffects, Int32[] finalEffect)
>      at System.Windows.OleServicesContext.OleDoDragDrop(IDataObject dataObject, IOleDropSource dropSource, Int32 allowedEffects, Int32[] finalEffect)
>      at System.Windows.DragDrop.OleDoDragDrop(DependencyObject dragSource, DataObject dataObject, DragDropEffects allowedEffects)
>      at System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(DependencyObject dragSource, Object data, DragDropEffects allowedEffects)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.DragDrop.Implementation.DragDropStateManager.PerformDragDrop()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.DragDrop.Implementation.DragDropStateManager.StartAndFinishDragDrop()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.DragDrop.Implementation.DragDropMouseProcessor.HandleMouseMove(Boolean leftButtonPressed, Point viewRelativeMousePosition)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.DragDrop.Implementation.DragDropMouseProcessor.PreprocessMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.WpfMouseProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass37_0.b__0(IMouseProcessor p)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.WpfMouseProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass56_1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)

After this happens, the text that was being dragged is impossible to delete. Backspace does nothing, delete does nothing until closing and reopening the file.

I uninstalled then re-installed visual studio without success in fixing the problem.
I tried starting studio in safemode, same problem.